# How can i make a HTML button run three functions one after another

Tags: javascript, html

My code has three functions. I want one button to run function one when pressed the first time then function 2 when pressed the second time function 3 when pressed the third time and then for it to reset.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script> 
            var red = "https://s23.postimg.org/bo5a8hzsr/red_jpg.png"
            var yellow = "https://s24.postimg.org/dodxgn305/yellow.png"
            var green = "https://s29.postimg.org/5ljr1ha3r/green.png"
            var lights =[red,yellow,green]

            function changered()
            {
                var img = document.getElementById("light");
                img.src= lights[0];
                return false;
            }
            function changeyellow()
            {
                var img = document.getElementById("light");
                img.src= lights[1];
                return false;
            }
            function changegreen()
            {
                var img = document.getElementById("light");
                img.src= lights[2];
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="sequence" onclick="changeyellow" onclick="changered" onclick="changegreen">sequence</button>
        <br><br><br>
        <img id="light" src="https://s29.postimg.org/5ljr1ha3r/green.png" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the [CC-by-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a dissociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/5244995).

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one function and a global variable that contains the current color like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<script> 
var red = "https://s23.postimg.org/bo5a8hzsr/red_jpg.png"
var yellow = "https://s24.postimg.org/dodxgn305/yellow.png"
var green = "https://s29.postimg.org/5ljr1ha3r/green.png"
var lights =[red,yellow,green];
var currentColor = 0;

function changeColor() {
    var img = document.getElementById("light");
    img.src= lights[currentColor];
    if (currentColor === (lights.length - 1)) {
        currentColor = 0;
    } else {
        currentColor++;
    }
    return false;   
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<button id="sequence" onclick="changeColor();">sequence</button>
<br><br><br>
<img id="light" src="https://s29.postimg.org/5ljr1ha3r/green.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could handle it, but here's an easy one:

above:

```
function changered()
```

add this:

```
var cur_button = 1
```

Then change your button to this:

```
<button id="sequence" onclick="handle_click()">sequence</button>
```

and add this function:

```
function handle_click()
{
  if(cur_button == 1)
  {
      cur_button = 2
      changered()
  }
  else if(cur_button == 2)
  {
      cur_button = 3
      changeyellow()
  }
  else if(cur_button == 3)
  {
      cur_button = 1
      changegreen()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can use the switch statement, and simply reference the lights array to determine which to display next. Seems pretty painless.

```js
var red = "https://snowmonkey.000webhostapp.com/images/red.png"
var yellow = "https://snowmonkey.000webhostapp.com/images/yellow.png"
var green = "https://snowmonkey.000webhostapp.com/images/green.png"
var lights =[red,yellow,green]

handleClick = function(){
  var light = document.getElementById("light");
  switch (light.src) {
      case lights[0]:
        light.src = lights[1];
        break;
      case lights[1]:
        light.src = lights[2];
        break;
      case lights[2]:
        light.src = lights[0];
        break;
    }
}
```

```css
#light {
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button id="sequence" onclick="handleClick();">sequence</button>
<br><br><br>
<img id="light" src="https://snowmonkey.000webhostapp.com/images/green.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go

```
 <input type="button" name="btnn" onclick="runFunction()" />


<script> 
 var red = "https://s23.postimg.org/bo5a8hzsr/red_jpg.png";
 var yellow = "https://s24.postimg.org/dodxgn305/yellow.png";
 var green = "https://s29.postimg.org/5ljr1ha3r/green.png";
 var lights =[red,yellow,green];
 var a =1;

function changered()
 {
  var img = document.getElementById("light");
  img.src= lights[0];
  return false;
 }
function changeyellow()
{
  var img = document.getElementById("light");
  img.src= lights[1];
 return false; 
 }
function changegreen()
 {
  var img = document.getElementById("light");
  img.src= lights[2];
  return false;
   }

function runFunction()
{
if(a==1)
  {
changered();
a++;
    }
if(a==2)
{
changeyellow();
a++;
}
if(a==3)
{
changegreen();
a=1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/x1rqwzvy/1/

You shouldn't add more than one onclick in your html code. If you do the handlers will activate simultaneously. This means you have to handle the change with JavaScript.

To determine the light you would simply increment a value in the following example:

```
  function lightChange() {

  lightChange.incrementer = lightChange.incrementer || 1;
  switch (lightChange.incrementer) {
    case 1:
      changered();
      break;
    case 2:
      changeyellow();
      break;
    case 3:
      changegreen();
      lightChange.incrementer = 0;
      break;
  }
  lightChange.incrementer++;

  function changered() {
    var img = document.getElementById("light");
    img.src = lights[0];
    return false;
  }

  function changeyellow() {
    var img = document.getElementById("light");
    img.src = lights[1];
    return false;
  }

  function changegreen() {
    var img = document.getElementById("light");
    img.src = lights[2];
    return false;
  }
}
```

then just change the onclick handler to lightChange instead of trying to add three consecutive handlers.

```
  <button id="sequence" onclick="lightChange()">sequence</button>
```

Comment: Works, but here's my issue: other than the img.src, each of the change* functions are exactly the same. The redundancy is a possible place for breakage.

Comment: @Snowmonkey I agree that it's redundant but that doesn't necessarily make it susceptible to breaking. I built it the way I did not out of ignorance, as there are slimmer ways to answer this question, but I erred on the side of readability since someone asking this particular question is probably a bit newer to the language.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
var counter = 0;

function changeColor(){
    counter++;

    var img = document.getElementById("light");
    img.src= lights[counter % 3];
    return false;
}
```

and your html should be:

```
<button id="sequence" onclick="changeColor()">sequence</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function array and then remove entries from it once done.

```
var functionArray = [changered,changeyellow,changegreen]

function sequenceClick(){
  functionArray[0]();
  functionArray.shift();
}
```

Complete Code:

```js
var red = "https://s23.postimg.org/bo5a8hzsr/red_jpg.png"
var yellow = "https://s24.postimg.org/dodxgn305/yellow.png"
var green = "https://s29.postimg.org/5ljr1ha3r/green.png"
var lights =[red,yellow,green]

function changered()
{
var img = document.getElementById("light");
img.src= lights[0];
return false;
}
function changeyellow()
{
var img = document.getElementById("light");
img.src= lights[1];
return false;
}
function changegreen()
{
var img = document.getElementById("light");
img.src= lights[2];
return false;
}
  
var functionArray = [changered,changeyellow,changegreen]
  
function sequenceClick(){
  functionArray[0]();
  functionArray.shift();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
</head>
<body>

<button id="sequence" onclick="sequenceClick()">sequence</button>
<br><br><br>
<img id="light" src="https://s29.postimg.org/5ljr1ha3r/green.png" />

</body>
</html>
```